# BTRFS and Luks integration

Tags: btrfs, luks

I would like to build a RAID1/BTRFS/Luks setup. What I found about it so far is:

An encrypted Btrfs file system can be created on top of the dm_crypt disk encryption subsystem and Linux Unified Key Setup (LUKS) layer, which supports a variety of encryption standards. However, this approach disables some of the capabilities and advantages of using Btrfs on raw block devices, such as automatic solid-state disk support and detection.

What's the best approach to implement this solution?

```
/dev/sda1 < 500 Gb 
/dev/sdb1 < 500 Gb 

/dev/md0 < RAID1 stripe < Luks < BTRFS < snapshots
```

Would a setup like this work?

I can't see other way of doing it without losing BTRFS-es snapshot capabilities.
I could setup the raid without mdadm with btrfs like:

```
mkfs.btrfs -m raid1 -d raid1 /dev/sda /dev/sdb
```

but then I got btrfs right on the top where I can only drop luks encrypted images. Even if 1 bit changes inside an image will affect the snapshots of btrfs (aka it will copy the whole image file again)..

Comment: I don't know what automatic SSD support entails, but one of the features would be trim/discard, I guess. However, as best I know, you still can't trim a (normal) RAID(1) array.

Comment: With Oracle Solaris, the encryption capability in ZFS[46] is embedded into the I/O pipeline. << Maybe using ZFS instead can take care all the problems in one (Raid, Encryption, File system snapshots).

Comment: Is ZFS on Linux stable these days?

Comment: LUKS is perfectly capable of passing through discard. Exactly from where did you "find out" this information?

Answer (score 4):

The important thing to note is that if you use md for the mirroring and create btrfs on top of it with "-d single" you will lose the ability to recover from bitrot errors (btrfs will still detect them)

So the best solution for your case would be your second example:

raw device -> LUKS -> btrfs RAID1 from the LUKS devices

loan already answered the TRIM/discard part for you and there is nothing for me to add there

Answer (score 3):

> However, this approach disables some of the capabilities and advantages of using Btrfs on raw block devices, such as automatic solid-state disk support and detection.

`cryptsetup` supports passing TRIM requests; you just need to use the argument `--allow-discards` when doing a `cryptsetup open`, or using `discard` as an option when using `/etc/crypttab`. Do this before executing `mkfs.btrfs` and you'll see that it detects the SSD and turns on TRIM. You may also want to ensure you use `discard,ssd` as options when later mounting the filesystem.

> Even if 1 bit changes inside an image will affect the snapshots of btrfs (aka it will copy the whole image file again)..

BTRFS will detect any bit corruption in a data/metadata block and correct that block using the other copy (it won't copy the file). Snapshots reference existing data/metadata blocks and don't normally take up extra space. Should part of a block (part of a file) later change, a copy will be made and referenced separately (it won't copy the file unless the block contains the whole file). The unchanged block will not be copied, just referenced.